# Azure Cmdlet: Get-AzKeyVaultKey failing with Value cannot be null (parameter doesnt exist)

Tags: azure, powershell-cmdlet, azure-rm

I am accessing Azure via Az module by invoking following cmdlet:

```
$key = Get-AzKeyVaultKey -VaultName "myName" -Name "myKeyName"
```

following [Get-AzKeyVaultKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/get-azkeyvaultkey?view=azps-2.5.0):

```
Get-AzKeyVaultKey
   [-VaultName] <String>
   [[-Name] <String>]
   [-InRemovedState]
   [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

but I am getting following error:

> Get-AzKeyVaultKey : Value cannot be null.
>
> Parameter name:
>   keyVaultDnsSuffix
>
> At line:1 char:8
>   + $key = Get-AzKeyVaultKey -VaultName "myName" -Name "myKeyName"
>   +        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzKeyVaultKey], ArgumentNullException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.GetAzureKeyVaultKey

---

> PS C:\Windows\system32> (Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName "myName").NetworkAcls
>
> DefaultAction                 : Allow
>
> Bypass                        : AzureServices
>
> IpAddressRanges               :
>
> IpAddressRangesText     :
>
> VirtualNetworkResourceIds     :
>
> VirtualNetworkResourceIdsText :

Hitting same exception via Azure CloudShell:

[image: azure cloudshell]

Comment: Have you configured firewall for you key vault?

Comment: @test123 I haven't configured anything except than creating AKV and creating key in it, will need to check it

Comment: please check it.

Comment: @test123 Navigating through portal my AKV -> Firewalls and virtual networks -> All networks is checked. Added NetworkAcls from KV in thread.

Comment: Try to update the Az module with `Update-Module -Name Az`, then login with `Connect-AzAccount`, will it work?

Comment: @JoyWang Get-InstalledModule returns me **2.5.0      Az** and **1.3.0      Az.KeyVault** which should be the latest one?

Comment: Yes, did you login with `Connect-AzAccount`? If you run the command in the [azure cloud shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview), will it work?

Comment: @JoyWang Hitting same exception via Azure Cloud Shell. screenshot added to thread.

Comment: How do you create the key vault? Which type do you use?

Comment: @CharlesXu Created standard way using portal, and after enabling soft-delete using azure cmdlet.